# SQL Server : creating a MERGE out of an INSERT

Tags: sql-server

This is what I have so far.  What I need to do is tell it that if the FTPJobRunID does not exist in DAILY_JOBS then INSERT the row otherwise do an UPDATE if the FTPJobRunID already exists.

```
-- Insert into Table the Statistics for the FTP Jobs
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Filename VARCHAR(128), FTPJobRunID INT, FTPScheduledStart DATETIME, FTPJobStart DATETIME, FTPJobEnd DATETIME, FTPRerunAttempts INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
   SELECT 
      RIGHT(LEFT(CAST(l3.params AS varchar(128)), CHARINDEX(',', l3.params)-1), LEN(LEFT(CAST(l3.params AS varchar(128)), CHARINDEX(',', l3.params)-1)) - CHARINDEX('=', LEFT(CAST(l3.params AS varchar(128)), CHARINDEX(',', l3.params)-3))) AS Filename,
        l1.id AS FTPJobRunID, l3.time AS FTPScheduledStart, l1.launchtm AS FTPJobStart, l1.stachgtm AS FTPJobEnd, l1.reruns AS FTPRerunAttempts FROM [server].[database].[dbo].[tablea] AS l1
   INNER JOIN 
       [server].[database].[dbo].[tablea] AS l2 ON l2.id = l1.prntid AND l1.type = 6
   INNER JOIN 
       [server].[database].[dbo].[tablea] AS l3 ON l3.id = l2.prntid 
   WHERE 
       l3.id IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM [server].[database].[dbo].[tablea]
                 INNER JOIN [server].[database].[dbo].[tableb] ON (tablea.owner = tableb.id)
                 WHERE jobrun_proddt = @ProdDate AND owner_name = 'blah' 
                   AND jobrun_cmd IS NULL AND jobrun_params IS NOT NULL);

-- Remove " from tail of odd Filenames
UPDATE #TEMP
        SET Filename = LEFT(Filename, LEN(Filename)-1)
    WHERE Filename LIKE '%"'

MERGE DAILY_JOBS AS TARGET
USING #TEMP AS SOURCE
????

DROP #TEMP
```

With a little help from KumarHarsh this is the code requred from Merge down -

```
MERGE DAILY_JOBS AS TARGET
USING #TEMP AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.FTPJobRunID = SOURCE.FTPJobRunID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Filename, FTPJobRunID, FTPScheduledStart, FTPJobStart, FTPJobEnd, FTPRerunAttempts) values(source.Filename, source.FTPJobRunID, source.FTPScheduledStart, source.FTPJobStart, source.FTPJobEnd, source.FTPRerunAttempts)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
    SET Filename = source.Filename, FTPScheduledStart = source.FTPScheduledStart, FTPJobStart = source.FTPJobStart, FTPJobEnd = source.FTPJobEnd, FTPRerunAttempts = source.FTPRerunAttempts;

DROP TABLE #TEMP
END
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
MERGE DAILY_JOBS AS TARGET
USING #TEMP AS SOURCE
on TARGET.FTPJobRunID =SOURCE.FTPJobRunID
when not matched then
insert (col1,col2.....) values(source.col1,source.col2.......)
when matched then
update DAILY_JOBS set col1=source.col1............
where FTPJobRunID =SOURCE.FTPJobRunID
```

Comment: I get a failure "Incorrect syntax near 'DAILY_JOBS' on the 2nd last line which I've done like so -

`update DAILY_JOBS set Filename = source.Filename, FTPJobRunID = source.FTPJobRunID, FTPScheduledStart = source.FTPScheduledStart, FTPJobStart = source.FTPJobStart, FTPJobEnd = source.FTPJobEnd, FTPRerunAttempts = source.FTPRerunAttempts`

Comment: I get a failure "Incorrect syntax near 'DAILY_JOBS' on the 2nd last line which I've done like so -

`update DAILY_JOBS set Filename = source.Filename, FTPJobRunID = source.FTPJobRunID, FTPScheduledStart = source.FTPScheduledStart, FTPJobStart = source.FTPJobStart, FTPJobEnd = source.FTPJobEnd, FTPRerunAttempts = source.FTPRerunAttempts`

I got a bit farther by changing the line to remove DAILY_JOBS so it's just UPDATE SET.  However it's now crapping out on the WHERE saying incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Comment: I'm an idiot see my updated question your fix worked!